# Selecting Display:None With Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am practicing with JSoup to see the possibilities this amazing parser can do. There is one thing I am unable to resolve :

I need to remove tags with display none attribute. One obvious way is to use select :

```
doc.select("*[style=display:none]").remove();
```

But this doesn't apply to all cases. Sometimes, in style tag, there are more than one property, like style="display:none,width...." and someytimes, there are spaces, colons etc like  style="display: none;".

I tried to solve this by applying :

```
if(!doc.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("style", "display").isEmpty()){
        if(!doc.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("style", "none").isEmpty()){

        // Not sure what to remove here.    


        }

    }
```

What should be the approach to get this done?

Answer (score 4):

You could try the `valContaining` construct for your selector like so:

```
doc.select("*[style*=display:none]").remove();
```

If this does not match what you want, try checking out the documentation here for more options:

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

Comment: seems like regex is an option.